# More efficient circuit than using a relay?

Tags: relay

I've built a circuit that uses a 24 hour rotary plug in timer.
[24 hour timer][1]

I cannibalised it to be part of a circuit I don't want turning on while I'm asleep. I have a sump pump under my house and the lowest part of the house is directly under my bedroom.

I've set the pins on the timer so it won't come on after 10PM and before 7AM. The output of this timer is 230 v AC. I'm using the output to drive a 230 v AC relay, and the relay switches 9 v DC to complete a circuit to operate a sump pump. The circuit times how long the sump pump is on for, and the pump can be triggered by a push button in the house.

So as a block it works as such:
24 hour timer -> relay -> timing circuit -> sump pump.

What would be a better solution than using a 230 volt relay to simply act as a switch to operate 9 volts DC?

I've already purchased the relay and used it. They now cost $47.90 at my local electronics retailer. So it's a pretty expensive way to switch 9 volts DC.

Comment: You say efficiency but it doesn't sound like you really mean efficiency since it doesn't sound like power consumption matters at all. There are MUCH cheaper relays. If you're switching DC you can use a single transistor, but if you want to drive it with 230V that's more complicated.

Comment: Perhaps I should have used the word economical rather than efficient.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds more like that's what you're after. You can edit your post if you wish. A cheaper relay would be the most straightforward solution if it's about cost. How much current is there for this 9VDC? Is it just a signal current to trigger the motor or is the motor actually powered off 9VDC? Because 9VDC seems awfully low for a sump pump motor voltage.

Comment: @DKNguyen Indeed, but if it is actually driving a motor and the OP has limited electronics knowledge, then relays are a good solution, since protecting a MOSFET from inductive loads might turn a bit more intricate.

Comment: The only things dissipating power would be the coil current and contact resistance. Compare your relay options and what voltages you already have available to drive it.

Comment: Why exactly is there a timing circuit? Every sump pump application I know uses a float switch to kick the pump on. Then, after the water level recedes, the the float switch turns off the pump. This is application should be water-level driven, not timer driven.

Comment: This is something I knocked together back in 2010. I built a circuit with a 555 chip that runs for x seconds after a separate float switch drops down. It does work, but in the interests of learning better ways to design and build circuits with a practical use, I thought I'd get some feedback from this forum. The 24 hour timer I initially used is just a mechanical rotary timer you can set the on/off pins down to a 15 minute time period. As the timer rotates, it switches a small microswitch to switch 10 amps 230 volts AC.

Comment: I used this power source to switch my 230 volt AC relay to work in series with the float switch and the 555 circuit to tell the pump when to switch on. I see someone else has commented that a pump should use water level rather than a time interval to control the pump. Yes, that's probably the better way to do things. However, I found that the particular sump pump I purchased tended to shut off before the water level had dropped all the way to its base. That's why I opted for a timing based system.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to plug an inexpensive (possibly one you have lying around) AC adapter into the timer and use an inexpensive DC-coil relay to switch the 9V. The adapter provides the galvanic isolation and allows you to use a very inexpensive DC-coil relay.

Comment: You could just plug a 9V AC-DC adapter into the timer so it gets powered and depowered directly and directly use the 9V output, assuming it can supply enough current.

Answer (score 0):

So how good is your electronic knowledge?

How much current can the output of the timer at 230 V ac handle? Maybe you could use them directly to drive the power supply of the pump setup? The downside would be that the pump could only be operated by the timer.

An alternative would be to get rid of the timer and get an microcontroller with wifi or an RTC for the timing (maybe the onboard crystal of the microcontroller will be accurate enough for your timing) and use a transistor for the switching of the pump timing circuit. This could then be used to either controll a small relais or a transistor. Depending on the circuit of the pump the transistor should be isolated from the power supply of the microcontroller.
For example an OPTOMOS or an Mosfet with an optocoupler or an optocoupler with the ability to directly drive a gate of a mosfet. The transistor and realis has to been chosen by voltage ( you said 9 V) and current and if you use a transistor for higher currents it should be cooled depending on its thermal specs.
Since this is a signal contact i dont think it has to handle much current but better to measure it.
If you use a transitor with a mosfet you have to get some sort of supply voltage from the pump or something like this and have to be sure it can be taken for driving the transistors gate.
The easiest way would be the microcontroller with an 12 V or so relais or an optomos.
Or you could simply trade you 230 V Relais in for some wich is driven by 230 V and switching maybe something like 12 V xx A ?
If you dont want to tinker around you could use finished solutions...
You even could use a smart relais.
But keep in mind the 230 V AC line is dangerous and should be handled carefully with knowledge so you don't electrocute yourself or others and don't burn the house down.

Answer (score 0):

24VDC is an industry standard for low voltages and relays, so go for that. In this case a relay which works on 24VDC coil voltage. There is plenty of such if you just search for "24VDC timer relay". That is:

- Get a 230VAC to 24VDC regulator - it only needs to be able to deliver the tiny bit of current needed to drive a relay coil.
- Get a 24VDC timer relay. Have it switching your 9VDC signal.
- As a rule of thumb, always place a flyback diode across the relay coil - especially if you got some manner of cheap voltage regulator of unknown quality. A plain 1N400x diode is good for that, for example 1N4001.